# Proving that certain powers of primitive roots are also primitive roots

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $z$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity. Prove that for any  $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $z^m$ is a promitive $n$-th root of unity. Verify each condition in the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

$$(z^m)^k=1\iff z^{mk}=1\iff n\mid mk\implies n\mid k\;,\;\text{since}\;(m,n)=1\ldots$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $z^m$ is not primitive $n$-th root of unity then there's $k<n$ such that 
$z^{mk}=1$, so $n|mk$ and with the fact $(m,n)=1$ we find by  Euclid's lemma that $n|k$.Absurd

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ We can easily calculate the order of any arbitrary element $\rm\:z^M.\:$ Let $\rm\: d = gcd(M,N),\:$ so $\rm\: \color{#0A0}{M = md,\ N = nd},\:$ and $\rm\: \color{#C00}{gcd(n,m) = 1}.\:$ By $\rm\,\color{#0A0}{ (C)\ canceling\ d}\,$ and by $\rm\,\color{#C00}{(E)\ Euclid's\ Lemma\ }$

$$\rm (z^M)^K\! = z^{MK}\! = 1 \iff \color{#0A0}{N\mid M}\,K\color{#0A0}{\stackrel{(C)}{\iff} n\mid m\,}\, K\color{#C00}{\stackrel{(E)}{\iff}} n\mid K $$ 
The order of $\rm\,Z^M\,$ is the least such $\rm\,K,\,$ i.e $\rm\:K = n = N/d,\:$ which $\rm = N\iff 1 = d = gcd(N,M).$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the set of $n$th roots of unity is isomorphic to the cyclic group of order $n$.The primitive roots are exactly the generators...